# ngrok with https on localhost returns 502

Tags: ngrok

I need to debug webhooks in an asp.net core 2 api hosted with kestrel.
It only runs in https : https://localhost:44338 (accessible, works fine)

I thought ngrok would be fast to use but I'm always redirected to an error 502.

I've tried those conbinations I found in other posts:

```
ngrok http -region=eu -bind-tls=true -host-header=rewrite localhost:44338
ngrok http 44338 -region=eu -host-header="localhost:44338"
ngrok.exe http -region=eu -host-header=rewrite localhost:44338
ngrok tls -region=eu -hostname=localhost 44338
```

added to

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://xxx.ngrok.io:44338/ user=everyone
```

but no change, any idea?

EDIT :

```
ngrok http -region=eu -host-header=rewrite localhost:8592
netsh http add urlacl url=http://xxxxxxxx.eu.ngrok.io:8592/ user=everyone
```

Comment: I have the same problem, do you remember what you did for it?

Comment: dont really remember specifically why I did it like this but I commented the http to https redirect in my code, then called the http endpoint with the edited added lines

Comment: We made a free VS Extension (sorry I don't know if you're using VS or VS Code, currently only the VS extension is released) called Conveyor that has a lot of the same functionality as ngrok.  https://conveyor.cloud/Help/Writing_webhooks_on_localhost_with_Visual_Studio_and_IIS_Express

Answer (score 0):

I've just found myself in the same predicament, I have a .net core 2.2 project using a Kestrel server which isserving up https on port 5001 (out of the box).

In order to get ngrok to work (version 2.3.29 - downloaded at time of writing as new PC which I've not used it on before).

Running simply just `ngrok http https://localhost:5001` returned urls that I can now use to debug webhooks.

Hope this helps.